# Count children add class based on length

Tags: jquery, count, children

I have several divs, each with the same class. I'd like to add a class ONLY to the parents containing a single item.

```js
$(function() {
   if($('.parent').children('.child').length !== 1)
   $('.parent').addClass('single');
});
```

```css
.single {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

In the first parent would have have the class "single" added, and the second parent would not.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

### <sup>✎</sup>Edit

**Demo 2** is an incomplete solution because [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is a *"lazy"* method, that being once it finds a match, it stops regardless of whether there's more than one match or not. In **Demo 2**, the original solution is commented out and an extra pair of `.parent > .child:only-child` elements was added to the HTML.

The new solution involves:

1. …the use of **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to collect **multiple** instances of `.parent > .child:only-child` into a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) — then…
2. …use **[`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)** to convert that NodeList into an array…
3. …so that we can run that array into [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array method which will assign the class `.single` to each `.parent`.

---

There's the `:only-child` **[CSS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/o/only-child/)** and **[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** selector. Find the only-child then it's **[`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)**. The jQuery version is very easy to use since it actually looks for a single child. Review **Demo 1** for a jQuery solution.

Similar to jQuery, JavaScript can use the CSS selector `:only-child` to find the it first, then it's `.parent` using [**`.parentNode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode). To assign the `.single` class, we use [**`.classList.add('single')`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Review **Demo 2** for a verbose JavaScript solution.<sup>✎</sup>

**Demo 3**, a CSS only example, utilizes the CSS selector `:only-child`. Due to limitations of CSS cascading nature, we cannot access the parent by targeting its child. Also, this goes without saying, we can't assign the class `.single` without JS/jQ.

### Demo 1 (jQuery)

```js
$('.child:only-child').parent().addClass('single');
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 2px dotted green;
}

.single {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}

.child:only-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      </div>



      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Demo 2 (JavaScript)

```js
/* Add a `/` to the start of line to enable code 

document.querySelector('.parent > .child:only-child').parentNode.classList.add('single');


//* Remove the `*` on the next line to disable the code
*/
var onlyChildren = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .child:only-child'));

onlyChildren.forEach(function(child, index) {

  child.parentNode.classList.add('single');

});
//*/
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 2px dotted green;
}

.single {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}

.child:only-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

### Demo 3 (CSS Only)

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 2px dotted green;
}

.single {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}

.child:only-child {
  outline: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the first demo *is jQuery*, I added 2 more demos: **Demo 2** uses plain JavaScript and **Demo 3** uses only CSS. **Demo 2** is a viable solution, while **Demo 3** is just an example of how limited CSS is in situations involving parent elements in a cascading relationship with their children.

Comment: Just adding a small detail here. Demo 2 and 3 both rely on the :only-child pseudo-selector, which is CSS3, and is not supported by IE8 and previous (also demo 2 relies on Array.prototype.forEach, which is not supported under IE9 either). Not a problem with Demo 1 though, since the selector was added in Jquery 1.1.4. So yeah, this looks like the cleanest option, but you have to take browser compatibility into account. For reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child for CSS and https://api.jquery.com/only-child-selector/ for Jquery

Comment: @aurelienshz [The axe was dropped on IE8, 9, and 10 last year](http://money.cnn.com/2016/01/06/technology/microsoft-internet-explorer-support/index.html). According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=only-child), IE8 has a 0.26% and IE9 has a 0.14% global share and that percentage are from enterprise licenses only. So IRL IE11 is the version we really should concern ourselves with if the clients are running Win8 and Edge for Win10.

Comment: You're perfectly right. Dropping IE<11 support is perfectly fine, it's just nice to be aware you are making this decision. But I meant my answer to say "be aware you're implicitely doing this perfectly fine choice" more than "don't do it".

Comment: I also have to admit I wasn't aware IE8 & 9 had so few shares. Guess I have kept the habit of checking for browser compat for IE<10, even though that's not necessary anymore for most real-life apps. Thanks for the eye-opener :)

Comment: I didn't know either, I looked it up after your comment. So thank you for challenging my work or I still would've thought the same as well.;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line :
`$('.parent').addClass('single');`.

By doing this, you're matching all the `.parent`. You need to iterate over them to selectively add the single class :

```js
$(function() {
   $('.parent').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.child').length === 1) {
      $(this).addClass('single');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.single {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

(Also fixed your condition, it should check whether the number of children is equal to 1, not different)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
$.each($('.parent'),function(){
   if($(this).children('.child').length == 1)
   $(this).addClass('single');
})
});
```

```css
.single{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `find()`. To find class with a `child` classname.

```js
$(function() {
   $('.parent').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.child').length == 1) {
      $(this).addClass('single');
    } 
  })
});
```

```css
.single {
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child</div>
  <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```